# mysql qt in linux and windows

Tags: mysql, qt

On a centos, 
qt creator 1.2.1
qtsdk-2009.04

what step by step is needed to create mysql driver, in linux and in windows.
such that running following command gives an positive output

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("xxxxxxxxxx");
db.setDatabaseName("xxxxxxxdb");
db.setUserName("xxxxxxxxxxx");
db.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxx");
bool ok = db.open();

Brgds,

kNish

Answer (score 0):

I used to have PostgreSQL(8.3) driver compiled successfully.Following is the batch cmds to do the job(replace the path with yours).

```
cd D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\Qt\2009.05\qt\src\plugins\sqldrivers\psql

D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\Qt\2009.05\qt\bin\qmake “INCLUDEPATH+=D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\PostgreSQL\8.3\include” “LIBS+=D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\PostgreSQL\8.3\lib\libpq.lib” psql.pro

@”D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\nmake”

“D:\SoftwareSetup\Dev\Qt\2009.05\mingw\bin\mingw32-make”

pause
```

If you use VC compiler,use **nmake** to get it compiled,
and I also referenced to following two links to find out library dependency:

http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-11/thread00265-0.html

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qdts-plugin-on-windows

This page from Nokia Qt doc may be helpful on *nix(and Windows):

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/sql-driver.html#supported-databases